# Changing the ngbDatepicker input template

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm working on an app that's using this example:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/rynxmynlykl

What I want is to display the **selected date** in a different format. Instead of `yyyy-mm-dd`, I want `mm/dd/yyyy`. The placeholder is easy enough to change but I'm having trouble finding what I'm looking for in the docs (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api).

The `ngModel` accepts an object which contains year, month, and day. Datepicker then formats it to the above format.

The closest answer I found is here but is now out of date ([How to change model structure of angular powered bootstrap ngbDatepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919275/how-to-change-model-structure-of-angular-powered-bootstrap-ngbdatepicker)).

Has anyone run across this scenario before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [the DatePicker documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#date-model), you can provide a custom version of the [NgbDateParserFormatter](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDateParserFormatter). See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjypx7) for a demo.

The following code for the parser/formatter is adapted from [this GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/nrobinaubertin/61ff1c3db355c74f4e56f485b566ab22) by [Niels Robin-Aubertin](https://gist.github.com/nrobinaubertin):

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@Injectable()
export class CustomDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {

  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
    if (value) {
      const dateParts = value.trim().split('/');
      if (dateParts.length === 1 && this.isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
        return { year: this.toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: null, day: null };
      } else if (dateParts.length === 2 && this.isNumber(dateParts[0]) && this.isNumber(dateParts[1])) {
        return { year: this.toInteger(dateParts[1]), month: this.toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: null };
      } else if (dateParts.length === 3 && this.isNumber(dateParts[0]) && this.isNumber(dateParts[1]) && this.isNumber(dateParts[2])) {
        return { year: this.toInteger(dateParts[2]), month: this.toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: this.toInteger(dateParts[1]) };
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
    let stringDate: string = "";
    if (date) {
      stringDate += this.isNumber(date.month) ? this.padNumber(date.month) + "/" : "";
      stringDate += this.isNumber(date.day) ? this.padNumber(date.day) + "/" : "";
      stringDate += date.year;
    }
    return stringDate;
  }

  private padNumber(value: number) {
    if (this.isNumber(value)) {
      return `0${value}`.slice(-2);
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

  private isNumber(value: any): boolean {
    return !isNaN(this.toInteger(value));
  }

  private toInteger(value: any): number {
    return parseInt(`${value}`, 10);
  }
}
```

The date parser/formatter is added to the providers in the module:

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, ... } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CustomDateParserFormatter } from "./datepicker-formatter";

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [{ provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: CustomDateParserFormatter }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.